# Oauth2 - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

I am using the following code to rendered the facebook login button

```
<div id="facebook-login">
  <script>
    FB.init({ 
      appId:"appid", cookie:true, 
      status:true, xfbml:true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function(response) {
      window.location = "http://xxx"; // redirect if user has logged in
    });
  </script>
  <fb:login-button perms="publish_stream"><?php print 'Login with Facebook'; ?></fb:login-button>
</div>
```

But it no longer works today, and I think it is related to the oauth2.

So I tried to update the code as suggested in [Facebook's developer docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

The new code:

```
<div id="facebook-login">
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({ 
        appId:"appid", cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true, xfbml: true, channelUrl: '//mydomain/channel.php'
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function(response) {
        window.location = "http://xxx"; // redirect if user has logged in
      });
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <fb:login-button scope="publish_stream"><?php print 'Login with Facebook'; ?></fb:login-button>
</div>
```

Now whenever I click the facebook login button, the chrome console keeps throwing the following error
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/login.php?...

I think it is a js cross domain issue, but I have setup the channel url. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Regards,
Kit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer. the get_facebook_cookie() no longer works for OAuth 2.0. we need the [facebook php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) as mentioned in [Facebook Developers – Facebook for Websites](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)

You can also tried the example in [Facebook Javascript SDK – A Simple Login Page with OAuth 2.0](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/01/13/facebook-javascript-sdk-a-simple-login-page-with-oauth-2-0/)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to replace the code to the new oAuth 2.0

```
param => scope
response.session => response.authResponse
response.session.access_token => response.authResponse.accessToken
FB.getSession().uid => FB.getAuthResponse().userID
```

link:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/